# defineConfig is undefined when required from @vue/cli-service - vue.config.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I'm trying to set up my vue.config.js file and found that issue when I use defineConfig method from @vue/cli-service.

> TypeError: defineConfig is not a function

vue.config.js

```
const { defineConfig } = require('@vue/cli-service')

module.exports = defineConfig({
  devServer: {
    port: 3001,
  },
});
```

defineConfig is undefined.
I was trying to look for it in cli-service folder, but (as suppose) there is no such method.

I'm using vue.js 3, yarn 1.22.17 and my @vue/cli version is 4.5.15.
Is it possible that defineConfig is for @vue/cli version 5.*.*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`defineConfig` macro is used by Vue CLI 5 not by Vue CLI 4, the right syntax for vue cli 4:

```js
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    port: 3001,
  },
};
```

You should upgrade to be able to use this macro.

Comment: This is incorrect information, Vue CLI also provides a `defineConfig` method (https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#vue-config-js)

Answer (score 3):

It seems you use old version of vue_cli.

Solution:

**UPGRADE YOUR VUE CLI TO LATEST VERSION**

Go to package.json and change @vue/cli-service to latest version

```
"@vue/cli-service": "^5.0.8",
```

Then will work, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The `defineConfig` function is available in `@vue/cli-service` v5 but not v4. I had the same problem and updating to v5 fixed the problem. You can also see it explicitly mentioned in the [Vue CLI docs](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#vue-config-js) (so it isn't specific to Vite).